# How do I filter by more than one measure

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Word Cloud visual. The size of my words are determined by my total number of employees. Employees is its own field. Two other fields are FTE and Contract and they add up to my total employees. I want to filter my visual by either FTE or Contract. But when I drag these Measures under Filters and uncheck one, it results in no data displaying.

[image: My Visual]

[image: My Data]

Comment: As a side note, is there any reason you need that many data-sources connected to a single workbook...?  Having so many open could potentially introduce some performance issues.

Comment: What is a better way? I create new data sources based on different tabs in Excel. The only way I currently know is to create a new data source when I need a new visual from the same workbook.

Comment: Yes, if the tabs are unrelated data then they should all be independent data sources.  I suppose it's personal preference, but once I've connected more than 5 or 6 data sources to a workbook, I look a creating a separate workbook, vs. cramming more in.  There is not hardfast limit that I'm aware of; however, I find that it can also help structure the intent of each workbook.  Take a look a this thread if you're interested more: https://community.tableau.com/thread/138319

Answer (score 1):

From your excel snapshot, it looks like you have a column for FTE and Contract.  Since all records have a value for each column, if you "uncheck" one of them.  All record will be filtered out.

From your question it appears you are trying to size the words based upon the number in either FTE or Contract (not total employees)?  If this is the case, I would recommend creating a separate calculated field that toggles between the two fields based on a parameter value.

Ex.  Calculated Field 1

```
IF [parameter] = "FTE" 
THEN [FTE] 
ELSEIF [parameter] = "Contract"
THEN [Contract]
ELSEIF [parameter] = "Total Employees'
THEN [Total Employees]
END
```

Ex. Parameter (String), List

```
Value              Display As
FTE                FTE
Contract           Contract
Total Employees    Total Employees
```

Comment: Is this IF statement meant for Excel? I tried to SUM Contract and FTE in Tableau and set that as the size in the shelf but that did not work.

Comment: @Chris This is meant for a calculated field in tableau.  You are looking to filter, but given the structure of your data, I believe that you actually want to toggle the column that is used to determine the size of the words?  You want to size determined by 1. FTE, 2. Contract 3. SUM(FTE + Contract) aka Total Employees. 

You can create a calculated field that will use a different column depending on the parameter value selected.  Then place that calculated field on the shelf for size.

Comment: If I put it on the shelf for size I lose my current size layout which it need

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure what you mean in your last comment.  Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: You advised creating a calculated field then placing it on the shelf for size. I believe I can only set one measure to size and the current measure I have set to size needs to remain.

Comment: @Chris  I must have misunderstood what you're looking to do by filtering then.  Can you elaborate on what you're desired behavior for filtering looks like? "I want to filter my visual by either FTE or Contract"

Comment: @Chris If you're looking to just filter the programs by the measure number in either FTE or Contract, just drag that new calculated field to the filter shelf, and use the parameter toggle to determine which field it is filtering on.

Comment: I have two separate numeric measures, FTE and Contract. Additionally I have a third measure, Total Employees which is how my Tree Map box sizes are determined. FTE and Contract add up to Total Employees. What I want to do is filter by either FTE or Contract. But when I set both of them as filters and uncheck one, my visual disappears like there is no data. I've also tried summing both FTE and Contract as a calculated field and setting that as a filter but it did not work.

Comment: @Chris Have you tried using the calculated field above as the filter instead of both fields?

Comment: @Chris Likely the reason why the data disappears is that by un-checking one filter, you're saying don't give me any values for that column.  And because all your data has the column value, there is nothing to display.  My understanding of your desired functionality.  You wish to filter your view based upon the measure values for either FTE, or Contract.  If contract is the case, you want to filter along the lines of "only show me programs for which the sum([FTE]) > 10"  Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, even though it is the sum of the two fields I am looking to filter by it is also its own column in my data source. Using it as a filter does not allow me to toggle between either my FTE or Contract measures.

Comment: @Chris the calculated field in my answer above does not include any summations.  You are using [Calculated Field 1].  You should be able to choose which field to filter by, by changing the parameter value.  Does that not work?

Comment: @Chris Alternatively, you don't even need to use the calculated field, just make sure that when you are filtering, with both FTE and Contract on the filter shelf, that you do not uncheck the fields.  When you wish to filter by FTE for example, leave all values available for contract, and only limit FTE values.

Comment: For example, I want to only see my visual where my measure has an FTE value. But when I uncheck Contract, all of my visual disappears. But leaving all values available for Contract does not let me only see my FTE data. Additionally, when I am trying to create a new calculated field using your Calculated Field 1 example I get the errors: parameter is underlined in red and it says, Reference to undefined field [parameter].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156858/discussion-between-tyvich-and-chris).

Comment: Chat is blocked by my jobs web filter and for whatever reason it is not working on my phone using the app.